# How to count how many times the program goes through a loop in C

Tags: c, loops, post-increment

So I'm a total C noob, this is my first question please be gentle. I have this program that scans patients weight in lbs and their temperature in Fahrenheit and converts the info in kg and Celsius. That's all fine and dandy but I'm supposed to add a loop so that users can scan as many patients as they wish (which I think I did) and to somehow count and print how many patients were treated. That part I'm struggling with, I think that would be the "post increment" but I cant understand the explanation I found for the life of me. If anyone got the patience to run it by me in simple words that would be really appreciated :)

Here's what the code looks like: (it reads in french but I think you'll get the idea)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

/* 1 livre = 0.454 kg */
const float LBS_EN_KG = 0.454;
int poids, /* le poids en livres */ patients; 
/* la température en Fahrenheit */
float fahrenheit, celsius;
char reponse;



do
{

fflush(stdin);
/* Saisie de données tapées au clavier */
   printf("Entrez le poids en nombre de livres et la temperature en  degre Fahrenheit \n");

   scanf("%d%f", &poids, &fahrenheit);
   celsius=(fahrenheit - 32)*5/9;


    /* Affichage de ces informations */
    printf("Le poids en kg est : %5.2fkg)\n", (poids * LBS_EN_KG));

    printf("La temperature en Celsius est : %5.2f Degre Celsius \n",celsius );

    printf("Voulez-vous continuer ? (O/N) \n");    
    fflush(stdin);
    reponse = toupper(getchar());



} while (reponse == 'O');

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Declare a variable and initialize it to zero: `int nLoops = 0;` then, somewhere in the loop, increment that variable: `++nLoops;`. When the loop exits, `nLoops` will be the number of times it ran.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a varible to store the iterations,for example:

```
int iterations=0;//very important equals 0 otherwise we dont know what iterations store and we need a 0 (cause i start counting on 0)
do {
       //your code
       iterations++;
} while (response=='0');
//here iterations stores number of times program go through loop
```

If you use increment like i++ or like ++i doesn´t matter cause these kind of increments are the same in this case, its gives priority to the operation over other operands, for example: assigments

```
term=term2++;
```

here term will be assigment to term2, then term2 incremented

```
term=++term2;
```

here term2 increments and then term also took its value

Remember pre increment and post increment gives priority over other operadns. 
I hope help you.